# Connect to localhost giving error in connecting

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, localhost

```
Dec 11, 2019 1:21:24 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Add3' did not find a matching property.
Dec 11, 2019 1:21:24 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Add33' did not find a matching property.
Dec 11, 2019 1:21:24 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.32
Dec 11, 2019 1:21:24 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Feb 2 2016 19:34:53 UTC
Dec 11, 2019 1:21:24 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         8.0.32.0
Dec 11, 2019 1:21:24 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 7
Dec 11, 2019 1:21:24 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.1
Dec 11, 2019 1:21:24 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Dec 11, 2019 1:21:24 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_221
Dec 11, 2019 1:21:24 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_221-b11
Dec 11, 2019 1:21:24 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Dec 11, 2019 1:21:24 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\HP\Downloads\apache-tomcat-8.0.32-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.32
Dec 11, 2019 1:21:24 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Users\HP\Downloads\apache-tomcat-8.0.32-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.32
Dec 11, 2019 1:21:24 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\HP\Downloads\apache-tomcat-8.0.32-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.32
Dec 11, 2019 1:21:24 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Users\HP\Downloads\apache-tomcat-8.0.32-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.32
Dec 11, 2019 1:21:24 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\HP\Downloads\apache-tomcat-8.0.32-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.32\wtpwebapps
Dec 11, 2019 1:21:24 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Users\HP\Downloads\apache-tomcat-8.0.32-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.32\endorsed
Dec 11, 2019 1:21:24 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Dec 11, 2019 1:21:24 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_221\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Shell 8.0\bin\;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3\bin;;.
Dec 11, 2019 1:21:24 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8082"]
Dec 11, 2019 1:21:27 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Dec 11, 2019 1:21:27 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Dec 11, 2019 1:21:27 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Dec 11, 2019 1:21:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 4612 ms
Dec 11, 2019 1:21:27 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Dec 11, 2019 1:21:27 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.32
Dec 11, 2019 1:21:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Users\HP\Downloads\apache-tomcat-8.0.32-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.32\webapps\docs
Dec 11, 2019 1:21:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\Users\HP\Downloads\apache-tomcat-8.0.32-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.32\webapps\docs has finished in 71 ms
Dec 11, 2019 1:21:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Users\HP\Downloads\apache-tomcat-8.0.32-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.32\webapps\examples
Dec 11, 2019 1:21:29 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Dec 11, 2019 1:21:29 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Dec 11, 2019 1:21:29 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\Users\HP\Downloads\apache-tomcat-8.0.32-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.32\webapps\examples has finished in 1,244 ms
Dec 11, 2019 1:21:29 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Users\HP\Downloads\apache-tomcat-8.0.32-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.32\webapps\host-manager
Dec 11, 2019 1:21:29 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\Users\HP\Downloads\apache-tomcat-8.0.32-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.32\webapps\host-manager has finished in 68 ms
Dec 11, 2019 1:21:29 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Users\HP\Downloads\apache-tomcat-8.0.32-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.32\webapps\manager
Dec 11, 2019 1:21:29 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\Users\HP\Downloads\apache-tomcat-8.0.32-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.32\webapps\manager has finished in 65 ms
Dec 11, 2019 1:21:29 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Users\HP\Downloads\apache-tomcat-8.0.32-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.32\webapps\ROOT
Dec 11, 2019 1:21:30 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\Users\HP\Downloads\apache-tomcat-8.0.32-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.32\webapps\ROOT has finished in 113 ms
Dec 11, 2019 1:21:30 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8082"]
Dec 11, 2019 1:21:30 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Dec 11, 2019 1:21:30 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2296 ms
```

my localhost:8080 cannot connect on chrome..it runs successfully but i wont show me the page for successful connection.
my system is windows 64 bit.

Comment: looks like your port is 8082

Comment: I've tried 8080 and few others..no success..is this localhost thing free?

Comment: *looks like your port is 8082* - did you try port 8082?

Comment: Yes.I tried port 8082.still no sucess

Comment: What's the error message? What status code and content is actually coming across?

Comment: Thanks guys it worked..i deleted the server,installed afresh from windows on eclipse and changed server location from properties..now i can see the apache homepage

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you have to do is change the port to 8082, if it still shows you nothing, the problem would be that it is not a localhost.

```
Dec 11, 2019 1:21:30 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8082"]
```

Also if you upload the code it would be easier to help you.

I hope I helped you with the information provided